# Add class to selected ng-repeat list elements

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, addclass

Hey I'm looping thru an array using ng-repeat in my template. The list spits out 9 list elements and I would like change the background color of the selected list element but I want to do it in a way where multiple ones can be selected and the color of the selected ones with a different background color. Initially I had passed $event to the click function on the list element and added a class to event.target but that put the class on all the list elements rather than the selected one.

```
<ul>
            <li class="info-items"
                ng-repeat="card in config.cards"
                ng-class="{'error-border': emptyCardsArray}">
                <div class="inner-text"
                     ng-model="userSelection.cards"
                     ng-click="addCard(card.name, $event)">{{card.name}}{{$index + 1}}</div>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

HTML:

```
$(event.target).addClass('active.cards');
```

JS:

The list that I'm repeating thru unforunately doesn't have a unique ID or I would have passed in the ID and created a condition to check whether the selected items have one and applied the class.

Comment: why do not you use [ng-class](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass)?

Comment: This directive handles multiple selections. http://jtrussell.github.io/angular-selection-model/

Comment: using ng-class applies the class to all the list elements rather than just the selected one @Artem

Comment: Check [Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/JVqDZOaHnt1vT85za0b6?p=preview)

Comment: I'm getting a selected is not defined error...maybe because I'm getting the array from an http call?

Answer (score 0):

It's a much better practice to simply use `ng-class` for this.

```
<ul>
  <li class="info-items"
      ng-repeat="card in config.cards"
      ng-class="{'error-border': emptyCardsArray}">
      <div class="inner-text"
           ng-model="userSelection.cards"
           ng-class="active.cards">{{card.name}}{{$index + 1}}
      </div>
   </li>
</ul>
```